React Native app crashes on launch on emulator with 16 KB page size support
As we know that, beginning with Android 15, the Android system supports development devices that are configured to use a page size of 16 KB. If any android app uses native code (C/C++ code), then those apps have to be rebuilt after doing certain modifications and tested thoroughly for any regression issues.
Mine is a react native android app, which does not use native code(C/C++ code) directly. But as per the steps given in https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/page-sizes#16-kb-impact,
if I analyze apk in Android Studio, I get a fair amount of *.so files in lib folder. These are probably coming from the 3rd party npm packages that my app uses.
After following all the mentioned steps in https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/page-sizes
I was able to install the app on emulator having 16 KB page size support. But when I try to open the app, it crashes with following log -

Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0x708d31bd64 in tid 22188

Raised the same issue on react-native github repo as well - https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/45054.
Has anyone found a fix for this? Or was anyone able to install their react native app on 16 kb supported device?
My version compatibility table for react native app -



Module Name
Version Recommended
Tested On




React Native
--
0.72.3


Android Studio
Koala 2024.1.2 | Canary 5
Koala 2024.1.1


Android Gradle Plugin
>= 8.3.0
8.5.1


Gradle
> 8.2
8.7


Build Tools Version
35.0
35.0


Compile SDK
35.0
35.0


Target SDK
35.0
35.0


CMake
3.22.1
3.22.1


Kotlin
1.9.22
1.6.0 (Issue on 1.9.22)



